# Why can't I choose value from select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

All data is shown and correct but I can't select any value from select2 dropdown.

What is wrong with my code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#basic').select2({
      minimumInputLength: 0,
      multiple: false,
      query:function(options) {
            var result =  ymaps.suggest(options.term).then(function (items) {
            var data = [];
            var output = {
              results : [],
              more : null
            };
            for (var index = 0; index < items.length; ++index) {
                console.log(items[index]);
                data.push({
                  id: index,
                  text: items[index]['displayName'],
                })
            }
            output.results = data;
            output.more = true;
            console.log(output);
            options.callback(output);
          });
      }
    }); 
    jQuery('#basic').on('select2:select', function () {
    console.log('on select: ' + jQuery(this).val());});
```

}

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vzexw4ky/24/

Answer (score 0):

After doing R&D on `select2` I found that `query` method is `deprecated` (See https://select2.org/configuration/options-api) so try to use ajax method.

Also there is one more issue when I opened the debugger I found that other `select2` drop down (I mean `select2` used on https://select2.org/) is adding options under drop down but in your case your select box is empty.

I would suggest try asking on their community https://forums.select2.org/